# The unit group of $ \frac{\mathbb{C} [x,y]}{y^2-x^4+1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to find the unit group of $$ \dfrac{\mathbb{C} [x,y]}{y^2-x^4+1}.$$

I think the unit group should be $\{k(x^2-y)^n |n\in \mathbb{Z},k \in \mathbb{C} ^{\times}\}$, but I can't prove it.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb C\langle x^2-y\rangle?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what is *really* meant is $\mathbf C^\times (x^2 - y)^\mathbf Z$. The OP's notation to describe the unit group was poorly chosen.

Comment: @KCd Don't answer for OP about what OP means.

Comment: sorry I didn't explain it clearly, $\mathbb{C}<x^2-y>= {k(x^2-y)^n | n \in   \mathbb{Z}, k \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, I will correct it.

Comment: That is what I had written too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field not of characteristic $2$ and $f(X) \in F[X]$
be nonconstant and not a perfect square. The field $F(X,\sqrt{f(X)})$ is quadratic over $F(X)$, and $F[X,\sqrt{f(X)}] = F[X] + F[X]\sqrt{f(X)}$ inside this field is analogous to $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ inside $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$ for nonsquare $d$ in $\mathbf Z$. (One difference is that $F[X,\sqrt{f(X)}]$ is integrally closed but $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ may not be integrally closed.)

From the theory of Pell's equation, $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]^\times = \pm\varepsilon^\mathbf Z$ for some unit $\varepsilon \not= \pm 1$ if $d > 0$, while
$\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]^\times$ is finite if $d < 0$.
The $F[X]$-analogue of this result says that $F[X,\sqrt{f(X)}]^\times$ either is just $F^\times$ or it equals $F^\times\varepsilon^{\mathbf Z}$ for some unit $\varepsilon \not\in F^\times$. This result goes back at least to Emil Artin's thesis and perhaps earlier (continued fractions in rational functions). Below is an approach based on a paper of Dubickas and Steuding (*The polynomial  Pell equation*, Elemente der Mathematik **59** (2004), 133–143). Your question is about $F = \mathbf C$ and $f(X) = X^4 - 1$.

Step 1: There is a multiplicative norm map ${\rm N} \colon F(X,\sqrt{f(X)}) \to F(X)$ given by ${\rm N}(a + b\sqrt{f}) = a^2 - fb^2$.
For $a(X)$ and $b(X)$ in $F[X]$, use norms to show $a(X) + b(X)\sqrt{f(X)}$
is a unit in $F[X,\sqrt{f(X)}]$ if and only if $a(X)^2 - f(X)b(X)^2 \in F^\times$
(this is an analogue of the units in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ being the $m+n\sqrt{d}$ such that $m^2 - dn^2 = \pm 1$) and conclude that
$F[X,\sqrt{f(X)}]^\times = F^\times$ if $\deg f(X)$ is odd or
if the leading coefficient of $f(X)$ is not a square in $F$.

Step 2:  Assume $F[X,\sqrt{f(X)}]^\times$ is *larger* than $F^\times$.  Let  $\varepsilon = a + b\sqrt{f}$ be such a unit
with $\deg(b)$ minimal (necessarily $b(X) \not= 0$).  For a unit $u = A + B\sqrt{f}$  not in $F^\times$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\varepsilon{u} & = & (aA + fbB) + (aB + bA)\sqrt{f},  \\
\overline{\varepsilon}u & = & (aA - fBb) + (aB - bA)\sqrt{f}, 
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\overline{\varepsilon} = a - b\sqrt{f}$. Show $aB$ and $bA$ have the same degree and their leading coefficients are equal up to sign, so
if the coefficients of $\sqrt{f}$ in $\varepsilon{u}$ and $\overline{\varepsilon}u$ are
both nonzero then the coefficients have different degrees.

Step 3: Let $s = aB + bA$ and $t = aB  - bA$ (the coefficients of $\sqrt{f}$).  If $s$ and $t$ are nonzero,
show $st \in F^\times B^2  + F^\times b^2$ and
conclude that $s$ or $t$ has degree less than $\deg(B)$.
(Recall $\deg(B) \geq \deg(b)$ by minimality of $\deg(b)$.)

Step 4:  Prove by induction on $\deg(B)$ that $F[X,\sqrt{f(X)}]^\times = F^\times\varepsilon^\mathbf Z$.

A unit in $F[X,\sqrt{f(X)}]$ that, together with $F^\times$, generates
all the units is called a *fundamental unit* of this ring.
For example, $F[X,\sqrt{X^2+X}]$ has fundamental unit
$2X+1 + 2\sqrt{X^2+X}$ and $F[X,\sqrt{X^4-1}]$ has fundamental unit $X^2 + \sqrt{X^4-1}$, where the second example is your question when $F = \mathbf C$.